# Linq error: Unable to create a constant value of type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create execute the following linq query:

```
result = (from user in context.vwUsers
          join boardMember in boardMembers
          on user.nationalNo equals boardMember.nationalNo
          select user).ToList();
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'DataAccessLayer.User'. Only primitive types or enumeration types
>   are supported in this context.

**More information:**
`boardMembers` is the result of the folloing linq query:

```
var boardMembers = (from complex in context.ApartmentGroups
                    where complex.grpId == complexId
                    select complex).First().Users;
```

I'm trying to get a list of `vwUsers` from db, and my code is trying to do the following:
1. Get a list of users from db (this is of type `User`).
2. Convert previous list into a list of `vwUser`s.

Comment: I think the `First` in your `boardMembers` is the problem. Maybe try `.Take(1).SelectMany(c => c.Users)` instead of `.First().Users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var boardMembers = (from complex in context.ApartmentGroups
                    where complex.grpId == complexId
                    select complex).FirstOrDefault().Users;
```

--for required result do this

```
 var result = from c in context.vwUsers
                          where boardMembers.Select(x=>x.nationalNo).Contains(c.nationalNo)
                          select c;
```

Comment: I ended up extracting the `nationalNo`s instead of `User`s using `User.Select(x=>x.nationalNo)` in the first query. But your solution is correct too.